# Access VBA Form Controls Disabled

Tags: forms, ms-access, vba, disabled-control

I have a book database and a simple form to browse through it and edit or create new records. I have a 'Go to first', 'Go to previous', 'Go to next', and a 'Go to last' button. What I was wanting, was for the 'first' and 'previous' to be disabled when the user was viewing the first record, and the 'next' and 'last' disabled when viewing the last record.

I'm using this code in the 'On Current' event for the form:

```
Private Sub Form_Current()
If Me.CurrentRecord = 1 Then
Me.Prev_Rec.Enabled = False
Me.First_Rec.Enabled = False
Else
Me.Prev_Rec.Enabled = True
Me.First_Rec.Enabled = True
End If
If Me.CurrentRecord = Me.RecordsetClone.RecordCount Then
Me.Next_Rec.Enabled = False
Me.Last_Rec.Enabled = False
Else
Me.Next_Rec.Enabled = True
Me.Last_Rec.Enabled = True
End If
End Sub
```

When I open up the form (it opens to the first record), all the buttons are grayed out; however, if I fiddle with the controls (just clicking them and/or moving them) in Design mode, and then switch back, the 'next' and 'last' buttons are enabled again (I'm on the first record, so the 'first' and 'previous' buttons are disabled, as they should be). What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What happens if you insert `Me.RecordsetClone.MoveLast` as the first line in that procedure?

Comment: That did it! Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspected the initial `RecordCount` was not reliable because the form had not yet loaded all the rows into its recordset when you first checked `RecordCount`.

You were able to force the recordset to finish loading before you checked `RecordCount` by inserting this as the first line of the procedure ...

```vb
Me.RecordsetClone.MoveLast
```